# Opencv ellipse() bug?

Tags: python, opencv

```
cv.ellipse( img, center, axes, angle, startAngle, endAngle, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]] )
```

The `startAngle` is the starting angle of the elliptic arc in degrees.If we set `angele=30` and `startAngle=60`,the angle of the starting line of the ellipse may be 30+60=90.Is that right?
But this is not the case.
My code:

```
img2 = np.zeros((500, 500))
img2 = cv2.ellipse(img2, (250, 250), (120, 40), 30, 60, 180, 255, -1)
cv2.imshow('2', img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Lets look at the result, the angle of the starting line(red line) is obviously not 90 degrees.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwuE8.png)

Why?Is it a bug?

Comment: looks like a bug or some unintuitive definition of angle inside of the ellipse. startAngle 0° and 90° steps are working as intended, but everything in between seems to be strange. Maybe they are using % of the arc length with full arc = 360° or something like that.

Comment: if you need a slow but accurate workaround, you can draw a circle arc (image and mask) from rotated ellipse drawing on a separate image, and draw a full rotated ellipse as a mask and then copy to your target image, using both masks.

Comment: sorry, no, it's not a bug (still you can use the workaround to fulfill your needs). See the drawing https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69 how the actual angles are projected to the ellipse arc.

Answer (score 2):

I got it.
`startAngle` is not the starting angle based on the ellpise.It is based on the circumcircle of that ellipse.Lets look at the following figure

[image]

It does a mapping operation.The blue curve is the output.